# How to 301 redirect from one url to another properly

Tags: permalinks, redirect

We have recently done a massive migration from a custom CMS to Wordpress CMS however want to figure out the right way to do 301 redirects from a situation where their previous URLs did not have any sort of date in the permalink but new one does

Old permalink: /category/subcategory/1234/slug (1234 = post id)

New permalink: /category/subcategory/YYYY/MM/DD/slug

What is the best way to do 301 for over 60k articles that follow this structure?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can use .htaccess (a file located at the root of the folder you are serving) and a regular expression to do the redirect. I used [Yoast](https://yoast.com/research/permalink-helper.php) to generate mine:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(?!page/)(.+)$ https://example.com/$4
```

In the regular expression above I match anything at the beginning then I match / followed by 4 digits (a year) followed by / followed by 2 digits (a month) followed by / followed by 2 digits (a day) followed by the page slug. $4 points to the 4th variable in (...). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982824/what-does-1-2-etc-mean-in-regular-expressions) for explanations.

In your example, though, you need to retrieve the date information given the post identifier. In this case, you may find it easier to use a Wordpress plugin that will handle the redirection for you. This [one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) (top result in Google) should do the trick.

PS: SEO best practices recommend moving away from date-based URLs. I am in the process of doing just that on my own sites. What's your reasoning for going the other way?